# Creating a regex with text, number and url combination

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I am trying to create a regex for the following combination

```
Alphanumerictext1:1234:12:124:aplhnumericText2:www.stackoverflow.com
```

In the above format it should validate even if the text has alphanumeric(first field) or incremental values separated by :.

Below are few valid examples:

```
Alphanumerictext1
Alphanumerictext1:1234
Alphanumerictext1:1234:12
Alphanumerictext1:1234::124:aplhnumericText2
Alphanumerictext1::12
Alphanumerictext1:1234:12:124:aplhnumericText2:www.stackoverflow.com
```

For that wrote a partial regex like below `^([\w\s\.]+(:\d*){0,3})$` but unable fulfil for last 2 values that are separated by `:aplhnumericText2` and `www.stackoverflow.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex to validate all the examples provided:

```sh
^[\w\h.]+(?:(?::\d*){1,3}(?::\w*(?::\w+(?:\.\w+)*)?)?)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QLRH3T/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[\w\h.]+`:
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group #1

  - `(?::\d*){1,3}`: Match `:` followed by 0+ digits. Match 1 to 3 occurrences of this.
  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group #2

    - `:\w*`: Match `:` followed 0+ word characters
    - `(?:`: Start non-capture group #3

      - `:\w+(?:\.\w+)*`: Match `:` followed by a host name
    - `)?`: End optional non-capture group #3
  - `)?`: End optional non-capture group #2
- `)?`: End optional non-capture group #1
- `$`: End